# When are graphs deceiving?

Tags: graphing-functions, big-list

What are some examples of functions or quantities relating to functions (e.g., limits) $f:A \to B$ where $A$, $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that require by-hand, "analytical" methods for analysis which are **seemingly contradicted by a graph generated by software**?

For instance, I recall that a Pre-calculus text stated that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos x^{6}}{x^{12}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$ (which, if I recall correctly, is proven using Taylor series) but the graph itself seems to suggest that it perhaps doesn't exist, due to the oscillations occurring around 0. [Graphs were generated via WolframAlpha.]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would say any time a value of a limit turns out to be irrational you are going to have a hard time figuring out what the limit is with just graphing assistance. For example, I doubt there are very many people who could look at a graph of $\ln{(2+x)}$ and recognize that $\lim_{x\to0}\ln{(2+x)}=\ln{2}$.

Comment: @DavidH - I have clarified my intent. Apologies for the edit.

Comment: Interestingly, if you write your example as $$\frac{1-\cos x^6}{x^{12}}=\frac{2\sin^2(x^6/2)}{x^{12}} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin(x^6/2)}{x^6/2}\right)^2$$ then the oscillations in the graph magically disappear. (Moreover, the limit as $x$ approaches zero is clearly $1/2$. :) Since the functions are *identical*, the graphs *should* be, too. So, you might well ask about deceptive graphs *in general*, without ... um ... limiting yourself to limits.

Comment: Also, in this discussion, one needs to be clear whether "the graph" refers to the mathematically-ideal object, or the software-generated approximation of that object. In the latter case, there's a good deal of literature about massaging a formula to (try to) avoid computational over-runs and under-runs and rounding errors and whatnot, all of which contribute to inaccurate (ie, "deceptive") graphs.

Comment: Graphing a quickly increasing function in the wrong window (too big) may make the graph "disappear" (as it could not be distinguished from the $y$-axis), similarly a slowly increasing function may look constant (with graph coinciding with the $x$-axis). This sometimes happens when a large range is given and the window is chosen automatically (but I assume it does not qualify as an answer).Also @Blue your comment shows that the graph in question is not deceptive, but rather that the graphing software gets confused and plots the wrong graph (due to rounding errors I assume).Your followup comment

Comment: @Mirko In a way, yes, it's due to rounding errors. But the phenomenon we see is more grave than ye olde bread-and-butter rounding error. It's called "catastrophic cancellation". For small $\lvert y\rvert$, $\cos y$ is close to $1$. Whatever data type is used, in numerical computations, the closest representable value to $\cos y$ is usually not exact (for $y\neq 0$). With the usual `double` type, the absolute error can be up to $2^{-54}$. Since $\cos y \approx 1$, the relative error is of the same magnitude. But then computing $1 - \cos y$, you get the same absolute error you had for $\cos y$,

Comment: but now the true value of $1-\cos y$ is small, so you get a huge relative error.  Basically, the plots above show the _relative error_ made in the computation of $1 - \cos x^6$ (scaled by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ and translated by $\frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: Here is [another example](http://i65.tinypic.com/2qnodbd.jpg) (for the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$) where rounding errors gives a very wrong graph. It does not matter how many terms one includes it still blows up around $n=50$ when using double precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost any example of catastrophic cancellation plus enough zoom will do the trick. Two cases:

A simplification of your example (simpler function, bigger zoom):

$$\frac{(1-\cos(x^2))}{x^4},\qquad x\in[-0.001,0.001]$$
[image]

A rational function with a removable discontinuity:
$$\frac{x^{50}-1}{x-1},\qquad x\in[0.999999999,1.000000001]$$
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try the function
$$
f(x)
=
x^2e^{2x}\left(\log(e^x+1/x)-\sqrt{x^2+2e^{-x}}\right).
$$
Playing with Taylor series shows that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\frac12$, but plotting the function for $x\in[1,50]$ is hopeless.
[See how Wolfram|Alpha plots it.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[x%5E2E%5E%282x%29%28Log[E%5Ex%2B1%2Fx]-Sqrt[x%5E2%2B2E%5E-x]%29%2C%7Bx%2C1%2C30%7D])
The reason is that you need to numerically calculate the difference of two very large but nearly equal numbers and then multiply the difference by a huge number.
Plotting on a suitable interval (depending on software) makes convergence to $-\frac12$ plausible, but I could not convince myself that a limit should exist by looking at the good part of the plot.

To derive the limit, you need the second order Taylor polynomial of $\log(1+t)$ and the first order one of $\sqrt{1+s}$ (with $t=e^{-x}/x$ and $s=2e^{-x}/x^2$) and estimates for the errors.
The "first order expansions" of $\log(e^x+1/x)$ and $\sqrt{x^2+2e^{-x}}$ agree for large $x$, which correctly suggests that calculating the difference numerically is very unstable.

If you want to study functions near zero, try plotting $f(1/x)$ or $f(1/x^2)$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

A classical example is $$\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Comment: Not sure if it qualifies though...

Comment: I have clarified the intent of the question. Apologies.